# Does your PC feels refreshed after hibernating as if it restarted?

Tags: windows, hibernate, reboot, desktop-computer

You know when your PC is on for all long time things start to slow down then after a restart everything feels fast again. Does the same thing happen on hibernate?

Comment: For me it feels slow after restarting when the System needs to load very much on startup... becomes even worse when there is no SSD present or the HDD is slow.

Comment: While any answer to this question is likely subjective, I'm inclined to say not, since during hibernation the entire state of RAM is saved to disk and then restored when woken, unlike a reboot, which clears RAM entirely and re-initialises the operating system, clearing much of its previous state.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf: That's a somewhat inaccurate generalisation. The entire state of RAM is not saved - a lot of it is discarded, such as certain driver state information, and most importantly disk cache which can make up the majority of your RAM. Devices and drivers are all re-initialized on resume too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Like *Crippedsmurf* says, hibernation causes the complete machine state (that's mainly RAM contents <s>but also for instance your video RAM</s><sup>*</sup>) is saved to disk, and restored on resume. After resuming from hibernation the machine is exactly as it was before going into hibernation, or at least that's the goal. Most programs will be oblivious of the hibernation, unless they rely on the PC's real-time clock, for instance.

---

<sup>*)</sup> *qasdfdsaq* is right, Video RAM is not saved *as such*. Rather, upon resume the screen is reconstructed based on each program's screen state, which was saved.

Comment: VRAM is not saved (at least not directly).

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - You're right. I clarified.